# Pronunciation of "negotiations"

Tags: pronunciation

I am pretty sure that I have heard the word *negotiations* being pronounced in one TV show in two different ways:

1. Nego(sh)iations
2. Nego(s)iations

What's the deal here?  Just different accents?

Comment: The pronunciation I imagine when I read (2) sounds non-native to me.  I could be wrong--could you make a recording?

Comment: What @snailboat said. The French would be likely to substitute "s" for "sh", as I believe they do in words like "station".

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/negotiation) says it can be pronounced either way. [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/negotiation?q=negotiation) only gives pronunciation (1). I think it's probably a British-American difference. But even in the U.S., pronunciation (2) is much less common. Was it an American TV show?

Comment: I found a non-American example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49zF8m7ys24

Comment: @snailboat Thanks, not only a good example, but also very funny :)

Comment: I was also going to say that #2 sounded British to me, but then @FumbleFingers (a Brit) said it sounded non-native, so now I'm stumped ;) I do know that I've heard pronunciation #2 before, though I can't think where, and I do know that it sounds "off" to me.

Comment: OALD gives both the British pronunciation as /nɪˌɡəʊʃiˈeɪʃn/ and the North American as /nɪˌɡoʊʃiˈeɪʃn/: http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/negotiation

Comment: A-ha, I found a reference!  http://phonetic-blog.blogspot.com/2010/10/negotiating.html

Answer (score 2):

In the midwest US, we use pronunciation #1.  I have even heard President Obama use this proununciation.

I have heard #2 used on the BBC for certain accents of British English.

Comment: You must have a trained ear! I (and probably most native speakers) would be hard-pressed to actually *hear* the difference. Since they don't mean anything, we "unconsciously" learn to ignore minor variations in articulation. Maintaining the **s / sh** distinction is obviously inherently tricky, which is why the standard representation of a drunk Anglophone speaking involves changing all the **s**'s  (and often certain other consonant sounds) to **sh**. Thus *"I'm shlightly pished!"* = *"I'm slightly pissed!"*. (BrE *pissed=drunk*).